# How can I replace the void pointer with something that has compile time type checks in this callback?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, void-pointers

I'm trying to create an event system with notifications via callbacks. I have the code written, but it is dependent on void pointers to work. After how hard void pointers bit me in my last project I would like to replace the void pointers with something that compile time type checks.

Here's the Event class

```
enum EventType {
  TEST_TYPE_A,
  TEST_TYPE_B
};

// used by event receivers
class EventHandler
{
public:
  virtual void handleEvent(EventType type, void* data) = 0; // PROBLEM HERE
};

// class to send events to objects registered for them
class Event
{
private:
  std::multimap<EventType, EventHandler*> eventMap;

public:

  void registerForEvent(EventType type, EventHandler *handler) {
    eventMap.insert(std::pair<EventType, EventHandler*>(type, handler));
  }

  void sendEvent(EventType type, void* data) { // PROBLEM HERE
    std::multimap<EventType, EventHandler*>::iterator it;
    std::pair<std::multimap<EventType, EventHandler*>::iterator, std::multimap<EventType, EventHandler*>::iterator> matches;

    matches = eventMap.equal_range(type);
    for (it = matches.first; it != matches.second; ++it) {
      it->second->handleEvent(type, data);
    }
  }
};
```

And here's the code to test the Event class

```
class Handler : public EventHandler {
public:
  void handleEvent(EventType type, void* data) {
    char *cp = (char*)data;
    printf("Handler: %s \n", cp);
  }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

  Handler handle;
  Event event;
  char c[] =  "what?";

  event.registerForEvent(TEST_TYPE_A, &handle);
  event.sendEvent(TEST_TYPE_A, (void*)c);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers! I'm kinda stuck on this.

Comment: The obvious answer is to move common functionality to an `EventBase` class, create different `Event` classes for events from different sources (for example, one class for mouse click, another for keystroke). Now each Event class can notify its listeners using a data type for event data that makes sense for that kind of event. If you want to keep separate events in the same class, as shown above, there might be some type erasure stuff you can do (using `boost::any` maybe?) to be able to strongly type your event data but still be able to stick it all into the same `std::multimap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's apply templates:

```
enum EventType {
  TEST_TYPE_A,
  TEST_TYPE_B
};

template <EventType> class EventData {};
template <> class EventData<TEST_TYPE_A> { /*****/ };
template <> class EventData<TEST_TYPE_B> { /*****/ };


// used by event receivers
class EventHandlerBase { public: virtual ~EventHandlerBase() { } };
template <EventType ET> class EventHandler : public EventHandlerBase
{
public:
  virtual void handleEvent(EventData<ET> const& data) = 0;
};

class EventDispatcherBase { // Shared logic
  protected:
    std::set<std::shared_ptr<EventHandlerBase>> handlers;
    void addHandler(std::shared_ptr<EventHandlerBase>);
    void removeHandler(EventHandlerBase&);
};
typename <EventType ET> class EventDispatcher : private EventDispatcherBase {
  public:
    using EventDispatcherBase::addHandler;
    using EventDispatcherBase::removeHandler;
    void dispatchEvent(EventData<ET>& data) {
       for (std::shared_ptr<EventHandlerBase> ptr : handlers) {
          dynamic_cast<EventHandler<ET>&>(*ptr).handleEvent(data);
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a wonderful example of templates with virtual functions.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with templates, but it would need quite a rework. Start by templating `EventHandler` by the kind of data to store, and create some common base `EventHandlerBase` class. For register and send event to do type checks you'll have to drop the enums and move to some typed kind of event id, so you can call `registerForEvent< TEST_TYPE_A >( &handle )` and `sendEvent< TEST_TYPE_A >( whatever_type_this_is )`.

You could have test types be defined as structs with a nested typedef declaration for the type of data. But then you have missed the ability to distinguish between event types at run-time. You will need to generate some unique value for each event-type type, like the result of `typeid`.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, to remove `void*` from `EventHandler`, you'll have to template `EventHandler`, and thus `Event`.  This sounds unhappy, until you realize that each `EventType` should be receiving the same parameter type, right?  If not, then you probably have other problems.  So you'll have one `Event` class for `MouseEvent`s and one `Event` for `KeyboardEvent`s, which makes sense anyway, since they come from different sources.  The only problem is now you can't have a single function that receives or peeks at all events, unless it's also templated.